# Section overlapping with div

Tags: html, css, css-float, block

Can anyone please tell me why the image is being pushed below the next section?
Please check http://test.cpathak.com/#work and under Graphic category, the third image. I am unable to fix that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a height on the 'Work' div as elements within this are being floated.

You could add a height to the div or add a "clear: both" in the CSS to the "contact" div.